# Get the path to work on ChartApplyTemplate in MT4

Tags: path, mql4

After reading the material I could find and trying various solutions, I still cannot get the `ChartApplyTemplate` to work.  The template is not applying to the chart being opened and the error I receive is 5002 - the file cannot be found.

Here is my code:

```
int iChartID = ChartOpen(sChartNameL,5);  ChartApplyTemplate(iChartID,"C:\\Users\\Jean\\AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\DA3C92B1779898CC0CACD726A655BECB\\Files\\ADX.tpl");
Print(GetLastError());
```

I have also tried:

```
  int iChartID = ChartOpen(sChartNameL,5);
  string sTerminalDataPath = TerminalInfoString(TERMINAL_DATA_PATH);
  ChartApplyTemplate(iChartID, sTerminalDataPath + "\\MQL4\\Files\\ADX.tpl");
```

I have tried to place the template in various directories. Files as stated above but I have also tried to insert a files subdirectory in the mql4\experts subdirectory and also tried to use the files subdirectory under the MQL4 subdirectory.  I have also left the template in the default templates directory.  I have tried these various locations as I believe Metatrader has a sandbox environment for where files may be accessed.

Please can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong variable type for your chart ID, it should be of type `long`. The code should read as an example.

```
long iChartID = ChartOpen("EURUSD",5);  ChartApplyTemplate(iChartID,"Popular.tpl");
```

For the location of the template file, from the documentation:

- if the backslash "" separator (written as "\") is placed at  the beginning of the path, the template is searched for relative to the path _terminal_data_directory\MQL4,
- if there is no backslash, the template is searched for relative to the executable EX4 file, in which ChartApplyTemplate() is called;
- if a template is not found in the first two variants, the search is performed in the folder terminal_directory\Profiles\Templates.